# Why "tableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)" give me a BAD_ACCESS error?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

[image]

I attempted to use this method to get the cell of that indexPath, but I got this "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error. 
But if I use `self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)`, it works fine.

I am confused what's the difference between that two methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [EXEC_BAD_ACCESS in UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2734413/2415822)

Comment: What information do you want to get from the cell? We know this approach won't work. But someone might be able to give you an alternative approach if you provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)` is the code is your View Controller, and it dequeue's a suitable new cell. Whereas, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method on the table view returns nil if the cell is not visible. Since `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is trying to work out which rows are visible, it's not surprising that it doesn't work.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652761/exc-bad-access-in-heightforrowatindexpath-ios) SO answer shows that calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` within `heightForRowAtIndexPath` recursively calls itself. Which is why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the cell does not yet exist. Consider that the tableview may be asking for the height so that it can construct the cell. Hence, you are asking for a cell before it exists.  I would have to run a test to be certain.

**UITableViewDelegate - tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:**
Asks the delegate for the height to use for a row in a specified location.

For this function you should be returning the height that you want for that cell.

**UITableViewDataSource - tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:**
 *(Required)*
Asks the data source for a cell to insert in a particular location of the table view.

**UITableView - cellForRowAtIndexPath:**
Returns the table cell at the specified index path.

Answer (score 0):

These Two methods is totally different, one is for the users, one is for the table view's delegate